# Ultra-Low Temperature semiconductors

Tags: thermodynamics, semiconductor-physics, material-science, electronics, quantum-chemistry

What benefits does cooling semiconductors have for technology or any other innovations? I understand semiconductors can become good conductors at high temperatures which are ideal for everyday things we use like laptops or phones. What I do not see is what is the benefit of low temperature semiconductors ? Is it like how superconductive material is great for the efficiency of flow of current or something completely different ? Maybe I am not asking the right questions but any help will be appreciated or even sources as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691062/ultra-low-temperature-semiconductors

Comment: What ?This is a link back to my question

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. Still, a possible duplicate at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32691/if-and-why-does-cold-temperature-affect-semiconductors